# countdown timer function and php with html tag

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

My code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `room_lists`";
$sqlquery = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)){

$toDay = strtotime($result['timeStop']); 
//echo $toDay;

?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=tis620" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function countDown(times){
    var toDay=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000); 
    var difTime=times-toDay;
    var day=0,hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0;
    if(difTime>0){
    day=Math.floor(difTime/84600);
    hours=Math.floor((difTime/3600))%24;
    minutes=Math.floor(difTime/60)%60;
    seconds=Math.floor(difTime)%60; 
    countDown_onLoad();
    }
    else{
        alert('asd');   //time out
    }
    $('.show').html(day+' Day '+hours+' Hour '+minutes+' Min '+seconds+' Sec ');
}
function countDown_onLoad(){
    setTimeout("countDown(<?=$toDay ?>);",1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
countDown_onLoad();
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="show"></div>

</body>


</html>
<? } ?>
```

Hello, I am a newbie using javascript. I have created countdown timer to use like auction website with js function that call from database(timestamp type) with php query, if the result is 1 row, it works fine but if more than 1 the result are all the same as last row in database. How can I fix this?

This is my output

```
0 Day 1 Hour 41 Min 25 Sec
0 Day 1 Hour 41 Min 25 Sec
```

Comment: quick fix : set `LIMIT 1` in mysql Query

Comment: It looks like you need to change the output approach as you've got a <head> and <body> for each row returned by your SQL query. You'll probably want to output the <html> document but then have you SQL look output different .js per row, something like doCountdown( element, <?php toDay; ?>);

Comment: You're outputting a whole html document for EVERY RESULT in your query.

Comment: ^^^
Alright i forgot all about that Thank for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be outputting an entire HTML document (less the opening `<html>` tag and `<!doctype>`) for every counter.

The core problem is that you are using `$(".show").html(...)` to output the counter, which is essentially telling it to put that content in *every* `.show` element. The net result is that they all show the same thing: whatever the last counter is at.

Your approach is almost unsalvageable, but here is my best attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=tis620" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
    <title>test</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function countDown(){  
          var toDay=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);   
          $(".show").each(function() {
              var elm = $(this);
              var difTime=this.timestamp-toDay;  
              var day=0,hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0;  
              if(difTime>0){  
                  day=Math.floor(difTime/84600);  
                  hours=Math.floor((difTime/3600))%24;  
                  minutes=Math.floor(difTime/60)%60;  
                  seconds=Math.floor(difTime)%60;   
              }  
              else{  
                  alert('asd');   //time out  
                  elm.removeClass("show");
              }  
              elm.html(day+' Day '+hours+' Hour '+minutes+' Min '+seconds+' Sec ');  
          });
      }  
      function countDown_onLoad(){  
          $(".show").each(function() {
              this.timestamp = parseInt(this.firstChild.nodeValue,10);
          });
          setInterval(countDown,1000);
      }  
      $(document).ready(function() {  
          countDown_onLoad();  
      });  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>
    <?php
      $sql="SELECT * FROM `room_lists`";   
      $sqlquery = mysql_query($sql);   
      while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)){   
          $toDay = strtotime($result['timeStop']);  
          echo "<div class=\"show\">".$toDay."</div>";
      }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I do not use jQuery. I am only using it here because you were already using it. With that in mind I may have incorrectly used `.each()`. Please let me know if you encounter any errors and I will try to fix them.

Comment: Thank but is there any type that i can use for $(".show").html(...) ??

Comment: I don't understand your comment. `$(".show").html()` is a nuke, and shouldn't be used here...

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as Accepted by clicking the big check mark underneath the voting arrows. Then go to your other questions and do the same there.

Comment: I have a little question about after the time is out in else {} how can i update mysql database?

Comment: in html while loop i have this code
$room_number = $array['room_number'];
echo "<td align = 'center'>$room_number<input type='hidden' name='room_number' value='$room_number'></td>";

Answer (score 0):

if you are displaying countdown then there must be one time, not multiple, so first set `LIMIT 1` when you retrieve the value

instead of doing this

```
function countDown(times){
// blah blah blah
}
function countDown_onLoad(){
    setTimeout("countDown(<?=$toDay ?>);",1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
countDown_onLoad();
});
```

try with below approach

```
var countdown = function(myTime)
    { 
      // blah blah blah
    }
window.setInterval(countdown(<?=$toDay?>), 1000);
```

Comment: Overall, I'd rate this answer as "complete bollocks". Firstly, you try to enforce `LIMIT 1` when the question clearly is looking for a way to have more than one show correctly. Second, you use `setInterval` wrong by calling a function rather than passing it, and third you don't actually solve the problem anywhere.

Comment: @kol will you please suggest me to enhance my knowledge. what is the wrong with `setInterval`?

Comment: Like I said, you are calling a function instead of passing it. The more correct form would be `setInterval(function() {countdown(<?=$toDay?>);}, 1000);`

Comment: if i have no argument in JS function then does it make sense? i m calling a function with `window` object

Comment: But you *do* have an argument in there. If you look at mine, you see that I don't have any argument to `countDown`, so I can pass the name directly.